# Perl - getting the value right after a keyword is found

Tags: perl

I would like to get a script syntax that does the following:  Take the below output that is defined to a variable called @pc

```
Active connections: 47
server accepts handled requests
 101 101 2434
Reading: 0 Writing: 5 Waiting: 42
```

I want parse this output so that I only get the value associated with "Active Connections"

The expected return value would be only 47 in this case.

Comment: Why would anyone want to strike down this perfectly legit question?

Comment: @mvp Because the OP shows no effort to solve the problem himself?

Comment: @Robert: I don't agree on this one. It took myself quite a bit of time and learning Perl to even know that syntax `my ($x, $y) = $str =~ /regex with groups for x and y/;` exists.

Answer (score 2):

Use this code snippet:

```
my ($connections) = $str =~ /Active connections:\s*(\d+).*/;
```

Variable `$connections` will contain your answer.

You can also extract more than 1 variable at a time, like this:

```
my ($connections, $reading, $writing) = $str =~ /Active connections:\s*(\d+).*Reading:\s*(\d+).*Writing:\s*(\d+).*/s;
```

In this case variables `$connections`, `$reading`, `$writing` will be extracted at once.

If there is no matching pattern in input string, extracted variables will be `undef` - I recommend to add a check for this to detect that input string has no interesting data.

Comment: @Jens: this code was pretty self-explanatory. But I added some comments anyway.